# Select nested form

Tags: python, selenium

I know how to make a selection, but what about nested selection options?

I usually do:

```
form = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/form/fieldset/div/div/span[1]/select')
Select(form).select_by_value('gmx.org')
```

The `form`is correct because I can use `.click()` on it. But what about the selection tho? I want to select `gmx.org`. Thanks! :)

```
<select name="fieldSet:fieldSet_body:grid:addressSelection:domainSelection" class="form-element form-element-select">

    <optgroup label="FreeMail">

        <option value="option98">gmx.de</option>

        <option value="option99">gmx.net</option>

        <option value="option100">mein.gmx</option>

    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="ProMail">

        <option value="option101">email.gmx</option>

        <option value="option102">gmx.biz</option>

        <option value="option103">gmx.com</option>

        <option value="option104">gmx.eu</option>

        <option value="option105">gmx.info</option>

        # I want to select this
        <option value="option106">gmx.org</option>

        <option value="option107">mail.gmx</option>

    </optgroup>
...
```

Comment: do you get error or what?

Comment: this option has value `option106`, not `gmx.org`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option has value `option106`, and (visible) text `gmx.org`.

```
Select(form).select_by_value('option106')

Select(form).select_by_visible_text('gmx.org')
```

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working example

```py
html = '''
<select>
    <optgroup label="FreeMail">
        <option value="option98">gmx.de</option>
        <option value="option99">gmx.net</option>
        <option value="option100">mein.gmx</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="ProMail">
        <option value="option101">email.gmx</option>
        <option value="option102">gmx.biz</option>
        <option value="option103">gmx.com</option>
        <option value="option104">gmx.eu</option>
        <option value="option105">gmx.info</option>
        <option value="option106">gmx.org</option>
        <option value="option107">mail.gmx</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
'''

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
import time

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + html)

time.sleep(2)

form = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//select')

s = Select(form)

print('--- option106 ---')

s.select_by_value('option106')
print('value:', s.first_selected_option.get_attribute('value'))
print('text :', s.first_selected_option.text)

print('--- gmx.org ---')

s.select_by_visible_text('gmx.org')
print('value:', s.first_selected_option.get_attribute('value'))
print('text :', s.first_selected_option.text)
```